# How to do a text search on multiple tables linked by a linking table?

Tags: postgresql, join

I have 3 tables:

Images

```
"id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('images_id_seq'::regclass),
"created_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
"updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
"thumbnail_url" varchar(128),
"web_url" varchar(128),
"large_url" varchar(128),
"titlelong" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
"titleshort" varchar(255) NOT NULL
```

tags

```
"id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tags_id_seq'::regclass),
"tag" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
```

image_tags

```
"tag_id" int4 NOT NULL,
"image_id" int4 NOT NULL,
```

I need to do a search that looks in the image fields and tag field from tags but links the tags to images but the image_tags table.  I am not a SQL whiz but trying to get better.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    image_tags r
    JOIN tags t ON t.id = r.tag_id
    JOIN images i ON i.id = r.image_id
WHERE
    -- What ever you like to search for
```

And as we are talking PostgreSQL here you might consider renaming `images.id` to `images.image_id` and `tags.id` to `tags.tag_id`.
Then the query could look like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    image_tags r
    JOIN tags t USING (tag_id)
    JOIN images i USING (r.image_id)
WHERE
    -- What ever you like to search for
```

Three advantages:

- Less typing (less chances for errors)
- Keeping clear view (when it comes to larger queries)
- No identical data in different columns as `tag_id` and `image_id` would appear just once in the result

Comment: This helps but I also need to search the images table with that

Comment: You actually can, because you'll get all the columns of `tags` and all the columns of `images` as a result of that query. That is caused by `SELECT *`. `image_tags` will tell which tag belongs to which image. Just try and fiddle a little.